# Conver a PowerShell script into an installation package

Tags: windows, powershell, installation

I have a PowerShell script that configures a windows server and installs features, configures settings, and install basic applications.

Is there a tool that will create an installation package including some necessary utils?

Thanks

Itamar

Comment: If you havent found a way to do it i will be writing a tool to do this myself and was wondering if you might wish to clear up what features you would like to see in such a tool.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tryed this myself but i heard of a program called iexpress.